CakePHP 5 with latest CakeDC Users plugin
Went through all the setup and installation, got all my apis and connecting to google. However it's throwing and error message. So I debugged it some and at a lose or brain dead at the moment.
Traced it to the following function.
public function findExistingForSocialLogin(\Cake\ORM\Query\SelectQuery $query, array $options)
    {

        debug($options);
        debug($options['email']);

        exit;
        return $query->where([
            $this->_table->aliasField('email') => $options['email'],
        ]);
    }

Which debugs out to
ROOT/vendor/cakedc/users/src/Model/Behavior/SocialBehavior.php (line 285)
[
'options' => [
'email' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
],
]

Warning (2) : Undefined array key "email" [in /home4/benqpsmy/public_html/devsys/vendor/cakedc/users/src/Model/Behavior/SocialBehavior.php, line 286]
ROOT/vendor/cakedc/users/src/Model/Behavior/SocialBehavior.php (line 286)
null

Why is the first debug obviously showing the email key but the second is saying it's null?

Your $options variable has a key called options which is again an array, and it's that array that has an email key.

You are looking on a 2 dimension Array but you are looking for email key on the first level but it is on the second.
Explanation :
You have an array called 'options' ($options) with a key called 'options' and a parameter inside called 'email'.
In order to access 'email' you have to access the 'options' key inside 'options' array, this is : $options['options']['email'] instead $options['email'] which throws an  Undefined array key error because 'email' did not exist on the first level.
